# Required module does not update when the variable inside that module changes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a javascript file and in it I require another file that has a variable that changes.

main.js

```
let num = require("./extra").num
```

extra.js

```
let num = 5;

setInterval(() => {
  if (num > 0) {
    num--;
  }
  console.log(num);
}, 1000);

module.exports = {
  num
};
```

Now in the main.js file that variable num is always 5 and never changes. What do I need to do to get it updated all the time?

Note: I'm declaring the variable in main.js AFTER the variable changes so it shouldnt't be 5

Comment: In regards to your note, how is the variable changing? With your current code, I believe if you do a new `require` statement, it'll create a new instance of the `num` in your extra.js. So the one that was changed before, is no longer the one that is being accessed now.

Comment: In setInterval the variable gets decremented. So if it does that, when I require it it shouldnt be the default 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

in `extra.js`:

```
let num = 5;

setInterval(() => {
  if (num > 0) {
    num--;
  }
  console.log("in extra: " + num);
}, 1000);

module.exports = {
  getNum: function() {
    return num;
  }
};
```

in `main.js`:

```
let num = require('./extra').getNum();
console.log("initial value is: " + num);

setInterval(() => {
  let num = require('./extra').getNum();
  console.log("in main loop: " + num);
}, 1000);
```

Since the print statements in `main.js` output every second, you'll notice that every new call of `require('./extra').getNum()` will get the newly decremented value.

Answer (score 2):

Another perspective on this problem: you are dealing with the difference between "value" and "reference" when storing information in a variable and passing it around.

Primitives are passed by value (strings, numbers, booleans).
More complex structures are passed by reference (Objects, Arrays, Functions).

What is the difference?

**Pass by value:**

```
let a = 3
let b = a

console.log(a) // 3
console.log(b) // 3

a = 4

console.log(a) // 4 (obviously)
console.log(b) // 3 (when we assigned b = a, b was assigned to the value of a, which at the time was 3)
```

In this example, `b` does not inherit all of the properties of a during that assignment (`var b = a`), only it's value. This is essentially what is happening in the code you posted. Because num is a primitive, when you assign values to it, only it's value *at the time* is passed along. This actually happens in two places:

```
module.exports = {
  num
}
```

and

```
let num = require("./extra").num
```

In both instances, a variable is declared (or reassigned, in the case of module.exports, and assigned the value of `num` which is a primitive. Now those variables and/or object properties are "locked in" so to speak, unless they are manually reassigned elsewhere in the code to a different value.

**Pass by Reference:**

What I referred to above as a "complex structure," like an Object, is (in perhaps a simplistic way of stating things) essentially a *pointer* to a place in memory that contains references to other values (a.k.a. properties/methods). If that sounds abstract, that's because it is. Every time an object is created, the JavaScript engine reserves another place in memory for that object's properties to be collected and referenced. This creates some interesting scenarios, like:

```
const a = {}
const b = {}

console.log(a === b) // false!
console.log(a == b) // also false!
```

Even though we look at those objects and would say they appear to be identical/equal, they are actually both just references to places in memory, and two *different* places in memory, so they cannot be the same. However, if we assign both variables to the same location in memory, they will *always* be equal (and herein is the solution to your problem):

```
const a = {}
const b = a
console.log(a === b) // true!
console.log(a == b) // also true!

a.prop = 4

console.log(b) // { prop: 4 }

b.prop = 2
b.other = 3

console.log(a) // { prop: 2, other: 3 }
```

As you can see, now that both variables point to the same place in memory (`const b = a`), they will always "share" the same properties and therefore, the same values of those properties.

I hope that was helpful, and here is an implementation (probably not preferred to the singleton "getNum" option recommended by others, but certainly equally viable) of these principles that solves your original problem:

index.js

```
const obj = require('./num')

console.log(obj.num)

setTimeout(() => console.log(obj.num), 2000)
setTimeout(() => console.log(obj.num), 4000)
setTimeout(() => console.log(obj.num), 6000)
```

num.js

```
const obj = { num: 5 }

setInterval(() => {
  if (obj.num > 0) {
    obj.num--
  }
}, 1000)

module.exports = obj
```

**Happy coding!**

Answer (score 0):

`require()` is evaluated when the `main.js` begins to run (i.e. before the first `setInterval()` triggers), so `require("./extra").num` always return `5`.

Also since `num` is passed by value in `module.exports`, repeatedly calling `require()` won't help.

A working (not sure if best) way to do it would be:

```
let num = 5;

setInterval(() => {
  if (num > 0) {
    num--;
  }
  console.log(num);
}, 1000);

function getNum() {
  return num;
}

module.exports = {
  getNum
};
```

then

```
let num = require("./extra").getNum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with simple integer value as it passes as value and not as reference. But you can use an object instead

main.js

```
let num = require("./extra").num

setInterval(function(){
    
 console.log(num.value); // print 1, 2, 3

}, 1000);
```

extra.js

```
module.exports.num = {value: 0};

setInterval(function(){

    exports.num.value++;

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a diff answer. If you want keep the `num` and not `getNum()` you could use a class with setter and getter for `num`. For example:

**extra.js**

```js
module.exports = new class ExtraContainer {

    constructor() {
        this._num = 5;

        // Do stuff...
        setInterval(() => {
            if (this._num > 0) {
                --this._num;
            }
            // console.log(this._num);
        }, 1000);
    }

    get num() {
        return this._num;
    }

    set num(value) {
        // Do nothing...
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```js
const extra = require("./extra");

console.log(extra.num);

// 2 sec timeout
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(extra.num);
}, 2000);

// 5 sec timeout
setTimeout(() => {
    extra.num = 1000; // The user cant modify the variable
    console.log(extra.num);
}, 6000);

// 7 sec timeout
setTimeout(() => {
    extra._num = 1000; // You can avoid this with diff teqniques
    console.log(extra.num);
}, 7000);
```

**output**

```
5
3
0
1000
```

***WARNING: You don't destroy the `setInterval`, so your code never ends.***